# ¿Cuál es la ruta para guardar un PDF en Android?

Tags: android, c#, pdf, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.forms en la cual estoy generando un PDF, pero este PDF debo guardarlo dentro del teléfono en una carpeta que debo crear.

El problema lo tengo porque no sé cómo acceder al almacenamiento interno (o puede ser el externo tambien) para poder guardar el PDF.

Alguien puede ayudarme?!

---

[Edit]

Agrego el código de cuando crea el PDF

```
string filename = Configuraciones.PathApp + "/HolaMundo.pdf";
//filename queda como: /data/user/0/GenerarPDF.android/files/HolaMundo.pdf

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filename);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter escritor = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
doc.AddTitle("Mi primer PDF");
doc.Open();
...
```

---

[Edit 2]

Acá dejo el [proyecto](https://mega.nz/#!WOxCTSoI!SgnfnsIBMAJ3Koh8-H60IDN6FfyCfldSHOnyamige64) que estuve utilizando para probar todo lo que encontré hasta ahora...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución...

Para poder acceder a la memoria del dispositivo, tenemos los siguientes directorios: "/" es la raíz del dispositivo, "/mnt/sdcard" es la raíz de la memoria interna y "/mnt/sdcard-ext" es la raíz de la memoria externa (SD)... Estos datos tuve que ponerlos a mano desde el `MainActivity.cs` ya que de otra forma no podía acceder a estos directorios. Esto funciona correctamente ya que desde el MainActivity pude crear una carpeta de prueba.

Answer (score 1):

Para persistir un archivo de forma local debes acceder al local storage

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
```

a partir de esta podras crear carpetas y usar el `CreateFileAsync()`

[File System Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/pclstorage)

Para esto evalua [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) alli tendras las clases he interfaces que necesitas

---

Tambien se podria evaluar aplicar

[Xamarin – Write file to SD Card in Android](https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/xamarin-write-file-to-sd-card-in-android/)

usando

```
Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path
```

[Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory/)

pero como veras debes habilitar esto en el `manifest`

Otra alternativa

```
var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Comment: Agarre el ejemplo que muestra en el link que pasaste... Ese que crea la carpeta y luego el archivo "MyFile.txt" pero no encuentro ni la carpeta ni el archivo dentro de mi dispositivo... estoy usando un Moto G5S y no hay rastro de ninguna de las 2 cosas...

Comment: Desde la App puedo acceder al archivo creado, pero desde el teléfono no puedo ver la carpeta del local storage...

Comment: como accedes a la carpeta desde el telefono?, intentaste conectar el cell por usb a la pc para asi inspeccionar las carpetas

Comment: Estoy buscando la carpeta desde la App "Archivos Moto" y desde la PC... pero cuando hago el debug rootFolder tiene el siguiente valor: "/data/user/0/GenerarPDF.android/files/MySubFolder/MyFile.txt" y no tengo ni idea de donde está la carpeta data y desde PC busco "MySubFolder" y no devuelve resultados

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device analiza la ultima respuesta

Comment: Analizando las respuestas de esa pregunta, no me sirve este paquete... porque el PDF se estaría generando en la carpeta de la App la cual solo se puede acceder desde la App o que el dispositivo esté rooteado. Yo necesito que el PDF quede guardado dentro del Almacenamiento Interno del dispositivo o a lo sumo, dentro de la tarjeta SD

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando alternativas de aceso a otras carpetas donde podrias persistir el archivo

Comment: Debo estar explicandome mal yo... el problema no lo tengo para escribir o leer el archivo, porque eso puedo hacerlo sin problemas... el problema que tengo es que no puedo verlo desde el teléfono. Si yo quiero guardar el archivo en la carpeta "DCIM" de la SD por ejemplo, no puedo porque todos los directorios que me traen las sentencias que me pasaste son el directorio local de la App el cual no se puede acceder desde el dispositivo ni desde la PC